# Bash associative array error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

When trying the execute the following in bash

```
foo=foo
my_array[$foo]=bar
```

I get the error 'bash: foo: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "foo")'. But this works fine:

```
foo=hello
my_array[$foo]=bar
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not declaring your array to be associative, so it's assumed to be a numeric array. When bash tries to evaluate

```
my_array[$foo]=bar
```

what he comes into is

```
my_array[foo]=bar
```

but the array index ain't still numeric, so he tries to evaluate it again, leading into

```
my_array[foo]=bar
```

as you don't need to use the $ when in between square brackets. You can see that this goes on and on until a recursion level exceeded exception is thrown.

To solve it, just declare the array as associative:

```
declare -A my_array
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. But why does the second example in my question work then?

Comment: My guess is that, when bash evaluates `my_array[$foo]=bar` and expands it into `my_array[hello]=bar`, then it tries to evaluate it again but finds no match for $hello, so assumes it to be a literal string and thus stops evaluation, considering the array as an associative one.

Comment: @Win32: I guess it assings `bar` to ${my_array[0]}, it does not turn the array into an associative one.

Comment: Indexed arrays evaluate shell arithmetic expressions and use the result as the index to dereference. Arithmetic variables must be integers. If they are strings then Bash looks to the variable named by the value of the arithmetic variable recursively until coming across an integer. This is limited, so if the lookup is too deep, or cyclical, then an arithmetic recursion error is thrown: `a=b b=c c=d d=e e=f f=a; ((a))` will have the same effect. win32's solution is correct - associative arrays can only be explicitly declared using one of the declaration commands that have `-A`.